# AWS Glue- job runs with no errors, but output is not displayed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I have data in AWS MySQL RDS and the requirement is to grab data from a table to the csv file and place it in S3. To achieve that i am using AWS glue and have code as shown below. The job runs with no errors and the output is not displayed in S3 bucket. Please help.

```
 import sys
   from awsglue.transforms import *
   from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
   from pyspark.context import SparkContext
   from awsglue.context import GlueContext
   from awsglue.job import Job
    import boto3

    ## @params: [JOB_NAME]
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

    aws_region = "your-aws-region-code"
    s3_path = "s3-prefix"
    glue_database = "glue-database-name"
    table="glue-table name"
    target_format = "csv"

    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

    client = boto3.client(service_name='glue', region_name=aws_region)
    responseGetTables = client.get_tables(DatabaseName=glue_database)

    tableList = responseGetTables['TableList']
    tables = []
    for tableDict in tableList:
      tables.append(tableDict['Name'])

    for table in tables:
      datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_database, table_name = table)
      datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = datasource, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": s3Path + table}, format = target_format)

    job.commit()
```

Comment: Can you confirm proper s3 permissions for the role used by Glue and also try printing the contents of datasource using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html#aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators-schemas ?

Answer (score 0):

replace 2nd last line with this , actually it should s3_path instead of s3path

datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = datasource, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": **s3_path** + table}, format = target_format)